# How should one include jQuery and its plugins in a page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am very new to jQuery, I am customizing my PHP project and trying to include 4 jQuery scripts in my page. Until I include my fourth jQuery script every thing was working fine, but when I included the fourth one I lost all other jQuery effects. now If I remove the second. again all other three scripts work fine. Even I tried with `$.noConflict()` with every script I included in my page. I am using the following versions of jQuery in my Page.

```
jquery-1.6.2.js
jquery-1.8.16.js
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
jquery.carousel.2.1.js
```

Do I need to put my jQuery in a specific order,. or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Why would you add jQuery 1.6.2, jQuery Ui 1.8.16 and jQuery 1.4.2? You don't need two versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jquery-1.8.16.js` looks like it is actually jQuery UI.

`jquery.carousel.2.1.js` is a seperate plugin.

These are just plugins and should have no effect, but should be included after the main jQuery library.

`jquery-1.6.2.js` and `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` are versions of the jQuery library.

Do you actually need to include both of these? I would advise you remove 1.4.2 and fix any bugs that appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use **1** jQuery, **1** jQuery-ui and **1** jquery.carousel.

Having 3 different versions of jQuery is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention, i use different jqueries for different functions. say one for image sliding (1.8) , the other for Tabs (1.6) , one for form fields (2.1) so how can i use only one version of jquery. when i download the jqueries from net they come with these version files. can i use only one instead of all those.

Comment: You dont use different jqueries, you have misunderstood the concept of it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 jQuery reference on your page and 1 jQuery-UI reference. Because (most) versions of jQuery are backwards compatibly and have move functions and faster run speed.

So you need to remove the jquery-1.4.2.min.js reference.

The order it should be linked:

1. jQuery
2. jQuery-UI
3. Plugins

If you wan't to link from an external page (like google). You can find the minified versions here: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Most of the time it loads faster because a lot of people link from Google and it's already in there temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just include a single version of jQuery - the min version is the smallest in size and should be used in production ... then add any plugins (including jQuery-UI) you require - again add the min version if possible.

jQuery should always be added first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include every version of jQuery. Just consider using the latest version which *basically* contains all updates from previous releases.

Also please mind to check your existing functionalities.